# Python pandas: retrieve the field associated to the min of another (cross apply equivalent)

Tags: python, pandas, grouping

I have a dataframe that looks something like this:

```
primary_key    event_date    amount
x               Jan-2014       100
x               Feb-2014        90
```

I want to calculate the min(event_date) for each primary_key, and the associated amount. For example, min(date) for x = Jan-2014, and in Jan-2014 the amount for x was 100, so I want this output:

```
primary_key    first_date  amount
x               Jan-2014       100
```

In SQL I was used to doing this with a cross apply.

How could I do this in pandas?

Thanks!

Comment: PS other than calculating the min first, then doing a join on primary key and date

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df.groupby("primary_key").apply(lambda d:d.loc[d.event_data.idxmin()])
```

or a faster version:

```
idx = df.groupby("primary_key").B.event_data(pd.Series.idxmin)
res2 = df.loc[idx]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df.groupby(['primary_key','amount']).min()
```

Note that I'm assuming that event_date field in your dataframe is in pd.Timestamp or datetime format and is not a string.

Comment: Doesn't this group by each combination of primary key and amount?

Comment: Yes. Exactly. And I understand that it is what you want. Isn't it?

Comment: No. I can do this in two steps: 1) group by primary key and calculate min(date) 2) do an inner join between the starting table and the table calculated in the previous step, on primary key and date, to retrieve the amount

Comment: Ok. Got it. Then HYRY provided the solution.